# Multiple parsers calling each other?

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am working on a complicated system that uses a number of XML schemas and associated parsers. One of the schemas is used to hold general data that are accessed by all of the other schemas. I would like to maintain this division in the (flex and bison) parsers. So, if I parse the main XML file and get to, say, the tag `<matrix>`, I would like to call a `<matrix>` parser as a subroutine, return its content to the calling program and continue parsing there after the `</matrix>` tag. I have been looking around the net, but I have not found anything useful. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems easiest to maintain the common pieces in a separate file and to split the  individual parser components into two more files: Part 1 has the Prologue and the individual grammar rules, part 2 has the epilogue. Then the three files can be concatenated (in a Makefile) before calling the parser:

parser.y: parser.part1 common.inc parser.part2

```
    cat parser.part1 common.inc parser.part2 >parser.y
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. You shouldn't need a special parser for each distinctive tag. You should parse all tags regardless of their properties and link them to a tree. Afterwards you can validate the tree to ensure a correct consistency of nested tags. If the markup language you're talking about is really that special, then you could create a parser that takes rules describing each tag. In this case parsing and checking are done at the same time, most HTML parsers are implemented like this.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of a misunderstanding. I have three schemas. The first one describes inputs to an optimization solver and consists of something like 200 tags. The second schema describes the output of the solver and is a little smaller, say, around 100 tags. But they both share one element, describing a matrix. This tag itself has something like a couple dozen descendants. I would like to implement one parser for this matrix tag that I could then call in both the input and output parsers. This seems easier to set up than maintain a matrix parser in each of the other two schemas.

Comment: It seems like using parser generators has brought you more trouble than it solved. I could only advice you to handwrite a parser or complexity will become a long-term problem.